# problematical of static property when using parent::

Tags: php, oop

When I run this code:

```
<?php
require_once 'getdata.class.php';
class Header extends GetData
{ 
    public $headers;

    public function sayfaHeader($sayfa = 1) 
    { 
        return parent::$sql = "SELECT * FROM header WHERE id='" . $sayfa . "'"; 
        //$data = parent::getData();
        return $data;
        $this->headers = (object) $data;
        return (object) $this->headers;
    } 
} 
$header = new Header;
echo $header->sayfaHeader();

?>
```

I get this error code:

```
Fatal error:  Access to undeclared static property: GetData::$sql in C:\AppServ\www\ilk\class\header.class.php on line 9
```

Why I can't use parent:: word?
I want to only change variable value of *public $sql*

Comment: why are you using a static property? why have you got 3 returns in one function?

Comment: Your method isn't static so don't seem to be in a static context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We should see `GetData` parent class, at least. I bet $sql is not a static property in that class. In that case, if it makes sense to be static, declare it static, else replace:

```
parent::$sql = "SELECT * FROM header WHERE id='" . $sayfa . "'";
```

With:

```
$this->sql = "SELECT * FROM header WHERE id='" . $sayfa . "'";
```

Any object can always access to properties declared `public` or `protected` in parent class. You don't need `parent::` in that case.

***BTW*** I don't understand why you have all these `return` statements...

Comment: You probably mean `$this->sql`.

Answer (score 1):

To change public value  you can do like this:

```
 public function sayfaHeader($sayfa = 1) 
 { 
    return $this->sql = "SELECT * FROM header WHERE id='" . $sayfa . "'";
 }
```

Will call parent property and assigns value.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you're issuing a return and then you have code underneath it.  Once you issue a return, no code that follows will be executed, so hopefully you're not relying on anything underneath `return parent::$sql...` getting executed, because it won't be.

Secondly, you have *three* return statements in a single function that fall into the same logic block.  There's nothing wrong with having multiple return statements in a function, but they must be mutually exclusive as in the following code:

```
if( condition ) return $something;
else return $somethingElse
```

In PHP you can only return a single value from a function.  That value can be an array, which you store multiple values in if you would like.  Also, you can [return values by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php) and [pass parameters as references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php), but generally that's not a very good idea unless you have a good reason for doing so.

I'll reserve answering your actual question until I can see what `GetData` looks like.